# Pass props functional components react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and trying to pass props from one functional component to another.

Here is component 1:

```
import React from 'react'
import TeamItem from './TeamItem'
import KKR from '../../assets/smith.jpeg'

export default function Teams() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TeamItem title={1} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is component 2:

```
import React from "react";
import "./teams.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import KKR from '../../assets/smith.jpeg'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 445
  },
  media: {
    height: 240
  }
});
export default function TeamItem(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(props.title, '>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
  return (
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
  );
}
```

The `props.title` is undefined here. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new can you post your code here, because in paper it looks correct :) but after you post it there i will take a second look and fix it 100%

Comment: @dodo your code is right, please check properly problem is something else

Comment: As everyone mentioned, the code looks perfect :) Only thing I would suggest would be to  remove node_modules, run npm install again and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @dodo As you described here `Code` is looking completely fine to me. I tried it locally and got the value `1` from `props.title`. please try restarting your server.